# How do I remove Grub and restore the XP bootloader without access to XP setup/recovery media?

Tags: windows-xp, grub, restore, bootloader

I have a Lenovo T430, with Windows XP (32-bit). I tried to remove Ubuntu from my HDD by deleting the partitions in Disk Management. Now, when I restart my computer, I get the following message:

```
grub rescue>
```

I understand that I must use a Windows recovery CD to use Windows again, but I do not have one. How do I regain access to XP?

Answer (score 1):

Download Hiren's BootCD and boot it from a CD/USB. It contains many MBR tools (full list [here](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)), including [MBR Fix](http://www.sysint.no/nedlasting/mbrfix.htm) that you can use as follows:

```
MbrFix /drive 0 fixmbr
```

(I assume you have only a single HDD/SSD in your laptop and so its drive number is 0 (zero).)

Comment: First off, thanks for the advice. I know that I am not logged in, but I am Steve McC, I have three hard drives: 10 gb d:65 gb and C: 390 gb, which is where the partition was originally installed. So which one do you think that it would be.

Comment: Looks to me like you have 3 *partitions* on a single 500 GB *physical drive* (would be difficult if not impossible to fit 3 hard drives inside a laptop!) Use the command as shown above and be sure to accept the answer if it worked. If it didn't (though I don't see why it wouldn't), post any error messages displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you using GRUB2, you can boot up to Windows XP by this commands in GRUB rescue environment:

```
search --file --no-floppy --set=root /ntldr
ntldr /ntldr
boot
```

UPD:
After booting up to Windows, you can rebuild MBR by EaseUS Partition Manager (http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/rebuild-mbr.htm).